# E_FAIL when calling ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IImageServer.Initialize()?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine, windows-7

I am using ArcGIS Engine and Developer Kit 10 on Windows 7. Specifically, I'm writing an ArcObjects console program using Visual C# Express 2008.

I am attempting connect to an image server via a URL (e.g. http://server/.../ImageServer), but I get an HRESULT E_FAIL exception when I call IImageServerLayer.Initialize(). The full message is "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component." There isn't much information on this error. Any advice on what could be wrong? Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesRaster;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.GISClient;

namespace EngineConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static LicenseInitializer m_AOLicenseInitializer = new EngineConsoleApplication1.LicenseInitializer();

        [STAThread()]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //ESRI License Initializer generated code.
            m_AOLicenseInitializer.InitializeApplication(new esriLicenseProductCode[] { esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeEngine },
            new esriLicenseExtensionCode[] { esriLicenseExtensionCode.esriLicenseExtensionCode3DAnalyst, esriLicenseExtensionCode.esriLicenseExtensionCodeNetwork, esriLicenseExtensionCode.esriLicenseExtensionCodeSpatialAnalyst, esriLicenseExtensionCode.esriLicenseExtensionCodeSchematics, esriLicenseExtensionCode.esriLicenseExtensionCodeMLE, esriLicenseExtensionCode.esriLicenseExtensionCodeDataInteroperability, esriLicenseExtensionCode.esriLicenseExtensionCodeTracking });
            //ESRI License Initializer generated code.
            //Do not make any call to ArcObjects after ShutDownApplication()

            //Create an image server layer by passing a URL.
            IImageServerLayer imageserverlayer = new ImageServerLayerClass();
            string URL = "http://vega/ArcGIS/rest/services/grandcanyon/ImageServer";
            imageserverlayer.Initialize(URL); // "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."

            //Get the raster from the image server layer.
            IRaster raster = imageserverlayer.Raster;

            //The raster from an image server is normally large; 
            //define the size of the raster.
            IRasterProps rasterProps = (IRasterProps)raster;
            IEnvelope clipEnvelope = new EnvelopeClass();
            clipEnvelope.PutCoords(779000, 9628000, 786000, 9634000);
            rasterProps.Extent = clipEnvelope;
            rasterProps.Width = 256;
            rasterProps.Height = 256;

            //Save the clipped raster to the file geodatabase.
            ISaveAs saveas = (ISaveAs)raster;
            Type factoryType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(
                "esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory");
            IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFact = (IWorkspaceFactory)Activator.CreateInstance
                (factoryType);
            IWorkspace workspace = workspaceFact.OpenFromFile(@"c:\temp\fgdb.gdb", 0);
            saveas.SaveAs("clipfromimageserverlayer", workspace, "gdb");

            m_AOLicenseInitializer.ShutdownApplication();
        }
    }
}
```

This code is based on http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000047t000000.

Here's the exception detail provided by Visual C#'s error dialog:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
  Message="Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."
  Source="ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto"
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  StackTrace:
       at ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.ImageServerLayerClass.Initialize(String ServiceURL)
       at EngineConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\brown\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\EngineConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 35
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. It turns out the SOAP address needs to be used, which in my case is http://vega/ArcGIS/services/grandcanyon/ImageServer?wsdl. I obtained this address by going up a folder (http://vega/ArcGIS/rest/services/grandcanyon/ImageServer) and clicking on the "SOAP" link at the bottom. You also don't need the "?wsdl" suffix at the end of the address.

Answer (score 2):

I would try using ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind before license initialization, as shown [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000002nt000000).

```
STAThread()] static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Add runtime binding prior to any ArcObjects code in the static void Main() method.
    ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.Desktop);
    //ESRI License Initializer generated code.
    m_AOLicenseInitializer.InitializeApplication(new esriLicenseProductCode[]
    {
        esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeArcView
    }
    , new esriLicenseExtensionCode[]{}
    );
    //ESRI License Initializer generated code.
    //********************************
    // Insert code here.
    //********************************
    //Do not make any call to ArcObjects after ShutDownApplication().
    m_AOLicenseInitializer.ShutdownApplication();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things you can try:

- Make sure arcGIS accounts/groups have permissions to the `c:\temp\` folder and the `fgdb.gdb` file.
- Make sure the COM components exists on your machine. Try re-installing ArcObjects SDK and/or ArcEngine. It seems like the COM object in question might not be found.
- In order to debug, try to isolate the code that's causing the error. You sometimes get a better, more descriptive error.